# How does Perl avoid shebang loops?

Tags: perl

`perl` interprets the shebang itself and mimics the behavior of `exec*(2)`. I think it emulates the Linux behavior of splitting on all whitespace instead of BSD first-whitespace-only thing, but never mind that.

Just as a quick demonstration `really_python.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# the following line is correct Python but not correct Perl
from collections import namedtuple
print "hi"
```

prints hi when invoked as `perl really_python.pl`.

Also, the following programs will do the right thing regardless of whether they are invoked as `perl program` or `./program`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "hi\n";
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print "hi\n";
```

I don't understand why the program isn't infinite looping. In either of the above cases, the shebang line either is or resolves to an absolute path to the `perl` interpreter. It seems like the next thing that should happen after that is `perl` parses the file, notices the shebang, and delegates to the shebang path (in this case itself). Does `perl` compare the shebang path to its own `ARGV[0]`? Does `perl` look at the shebang string and see if it contains `"perl"` as a substring?

I tried to use a symlink to trigger the infinite loop behavior I was expecting.

```
$ ln -s /usr/bin/perl /tmp/p

#!/tmp/p
print "hi\n";
```

but that program printed "hi" regardless of how it was invoked.

On OS X, however, I was able to trick `perl` into an infinite shebang loop with a script.

Contents of `/tmp/pscript`

```
#!/bin/sh
perl "$@"
```

Contents of perl script

```
#!/tmp/pscript
print "hi\n";
```

and this does infinite loop (on OS X, haven't tested it on Linux yet).

`perl` is clearly going to a lot of trouble to handle shebangs correctly in reasonable situations. It isn't confused by symlinks and isn't confused by normal `env` stuff. What exactly is it doing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The relevant code is in [toke.c](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.24.0/toke.c#L5005), the Perl lexer. If:

- line 1 begins with `#!` (optionally preceded by whitespace) AND
- does not contain `perl -` AND
- does not contain `perl` (unless followed by a `6`, i.e. `perl6`) AND
- (on "DOSish" platforms) does not contain a case-insensitive match of `perl` (e.g. `Perl`) AND
- does not contain `indir` AND
- the `-c` flag was not set on the command line AND
- `argv[0]` contains `perl`

the program following the shebang is executed with `execv`. Otherwise, the lexer just keeps going; perl doesn't `exec` itself.

As a result, you can do some pretty weird things with the shebang without perl trying to `exec` another interpreter:

```
    #!     perl
#!foo perl
#!fooperlbar -p
#!perl 6
#!PeRl          # on Windows
```

---

Your symlink example meets all of the conditions listed above, so why isn't there an infinite loop? You can see what's going on with `strace`:

```
$ ln -s /usr/bin/perl foo
$ echo '#!foo' > bar
$ strace perl bar 2>&1 | grep exec
execve("/bin/perl", ["perl", "bar"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
execve("foo", ["foo", "bar"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
```

Perl actually does `exec` the link, but because it doesn't contain `perl` in the name, the last condition is no longer met the second time around and the loop ends.

Comment: Note: This assumes the OP launched the script using `perl /tmp/pscript`. The answer is slightly different when the script is launched using `/tmp/pscript`.

Answer (score 12):

The documentation for this feature is found in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

> If the `#!` line does not contain the word "perl" nor the word "indir", the program named after the `#!` is executed instead of the Perl interpreter. This is slightly bizarre, but it helps people on machines that don't do `#!`, because they can tell a program that their SHELL is */usr/bin/perl*, and Perl will then dispatch the program to the correct interpreter for them.

So, if the shebang contains `perl` or `indir`, the interpreter from the shebang line isn't executed.

[Additionally](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/be2c0c650b028f54e427f2469a59942edfdff8a9:/toke.c#l5116), the interpreter from the shebang line isn't executed if `argv[0]` doesn't contain `perl`. This is what prevents the infinite loop in your example.

- When launched using `perl /tmp/pscript`,

  1. the kernel executes `perl /tmp/pscript`,
  2. then `perl` executes `/tmp/p /tmp/pscript`.
  3. At this point, `argv[0]` doesn't contain `perl`, so the shebang line is no longer relevant.
- When launched using `/tmp/pscript`,

  1. the kernel executes `/tmp/p /tmp/pscript`.
  2. At this point, `argv[0]` doesn't contain `perl`, so the shebang line is no longer relevant.

Comment: And, since 5.24, the word "perl6" is not considered a match for "perl", meaning that if a program with a perl6 shebang is run by the perl5 interpreter, it will re-exec perl6, rather than try to run it itself. `perlrun` doesn't appear to have been updated to reflect this.

Comment: (if you're really determined to get a loop, you can probably get one by symlinking perl 5.24 as `perl6`, since the loop-breaking condition *doesn't* have this exception.)

Comment: @hobbs, The code to which I linked is for 5.24. Further details can be seen there, and in ThisSuitIsBlackNot's answer. I was limiting the answer to the scope of the question, but there are indeed other "hidden" rules.